# Samsung galaxy SIII is there a way to add a new call ring?

Tags: ringtone, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I proudly own this phone, but I can't find a way to set up a classic ring call. What can I do?
There's a way?

Answer (score 5):

In `System Settings -> Sound` you should be able to select `Pick Ringtone`. If you don't find the ringtone you want, you can use any MP3 or OGG. Just put the file on your sdcard in `/sdcard/Ringtones/`. Media scanner will classify anything in this directory as a Ringtone.